# How JPA and Spring Data repositories are correlated?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

For example lets consider spring data **CrudRepository#save()**. It is based on JPA em.persist() and em.merge().
Using save() for new entity we use **persist()**. After this operation entity becomes **managed/persisted in JPA**. JPA must track this entity and automatically update it in database when entity changes.
But using spring data we must "manually" use CrudRepository#save() to write to database changes of entity instance.

How **JPA auto-update** (when entity is managed) and Spring Data **repository "manual" update** (save()) are **correlated (practically and conceptually)**?

Comment: After calling save it is managed and you don't have to manually call `save`. What applies to JPA still applies when using Spring Data JPA.

Comment: 1)but if dont want entity to be managed by JPA - i cant use  CrudRepository#save()?

Comment: 2)What is the purpose of repositories if we can call em.persist() and then use only entity.setFieldname(...)?

Comment: 3)Spring Data is high level abstraction over JPA. The main target of Spring Data must be to encapsulate JPA. But we have to know  Spring Data + JPA because JPA in not encapsulated and JPA can make update queries
bypassing Spring Data repositories. Why it is so complicated?

Comment: It isn't complicatied imho. Spring Data makes it easier to write queries and map results. So instead of working with the low-level API you let Spring Data do that.

Comment: in SimpleJpaRepository method save() has @Transactional annotation. This means that entitymanagers transaction starts  from the launch save()  and commits after return? Therefore entity becomes detached?

Comment: Only if you run without a proper transaction. If you are following the best practices it is your service method that should be the transactional start/stop not the individual calls to repository methods.

Comment: 'What is the purpose of repositories if we can call em.persist()' - Well, I mean, at the risk of stating the obvious, nobody is *forcing you* to use Spring Data. BUT, as @M.Deinum already pointed out, it's an abstraction over JPA *and* Spring Data reuses the same abstractions for other API adapters as well. So, if you want to switch to, say, MongoDB in the future, the transition will be smoother if you are already using repositories